# How to get the tabs information in a salesforce account using REST API in python?

Tags: python, rest, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I have a `Salesforce` developer account where I have some bunch of tabs like below

[image]

I am using `simple_salesforce` library and I can access information of each tab just fine. For example If I need some information of `Contacts` tab, I make  a query like so

```
import requests
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, SalesforceLogin

# Create the connection
session_id, instance  = SalesforceLogin(username='abcdr@email.com', password='abcd',
                            security_token = 'Kds43Ddsd44DDSdsds4')   
sf = Salesforce(instance=instance, session_id=session_id)

# Query to execute
sql_query = "SELECT name, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Chen'"
information = sf.query_all(query= sql_query)

print(information)
```

Now there is something I do not understand. As you can see in the picture, the tab names are plural. But while querying, I have to provide singular name. So If I want to query something in `Contacts` tab, in my query I do `FROM contact` or If I want to query something from Leads tab, I do `FROM Lead`.

I do not quite understand why do I have to write in such a way. So to be sure, I would rather get the tabs information and then query on them. But I can't find how to get the list of tabs like Home, Chatter, Accounts etc. There is something called `describeTabs()` but nothing I could find for `simple_salesforce` library or any query that can get me the tabs information.

How do I get the tabs information?

Answer (score 1):

When you run query in Salesforce in such way

```
SELECT name, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Chen'
```

You query records of a database table `Contact` (in salesforce terms table is a sObject) and `Tab` is just a view for sObjects. Usually you do not need to work with tabs in you code at all.

There's a set of standard objects like `Account`, `Contact`, `Opportunity` and custom object which you can define, custom objects(tables) has a `__c` postfix

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_concepts.htm)

List of [standard objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm)

The set of objects which available for you in org might differ based on Salesforce edition (Developer, Enterprise, etc) and platform version Sales Cloud, Service Cloud, Marketing Cloud, etc

You can open setup and view a standard objects here

[image]

Custom objects and tabs

[image]